# The package system is broken using 12.04.2 lts

Tags: 12.04, system

When I run the update manager i get this "The following packages have unmet dependencies:

```
libefl-bin: Depends: libefl (= 201212281219-551~precise1) but 201303222352-21556~precise1 is installed"
```

But when I do `sudo apt-get install -f` in the terminal I get the same output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your package management is out of sync.  The version of libefl available by that name is newer than the libefl-bin that you're trying to install. [This PPA](https://launchpad.net/~hannes-janetzek/+archive/enlightenment-svn/+build/4392773) has the version of libefl-bin that matches the libefl you have (you might have to rebuild libefl-bin-blahblah and libefl-blahblah as libefl and libefl-bin though).

Answer (score 0):

Try this: https://askubuntu.com/a/142808/86944

You should always look for a general answer that may apply to your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Did you updated your system after installation? 
If the answer is "no", then you should do it now. In most cases this will simply solve your problem of unmatched dependencies. Both the system and software repository 
should be updated.
If you have successfully updated your system but the problem exist then try to remove the package or specific package dependencies and reinstall them again with ap-get or synaptic package manager.

Hope this helps.